# Where is the Google Public Key for JWT validation?

Tags: angular, jwt, google-openid

I have an Angular11 UI front-end utilizing Google's RS256 authentication by

1. `import { SocialAuthService, GoogleLoginProvider, SocialUser } from 'angularx-social-login';`
2. in app.module.ts adding
   `providers: [{ id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID, provider: new GoogleLoginProvider('my Google-Client-ID')}]`

When Google sends me back the JWT token, I send it to my NodeJS App server to establish a JWT-based communication for the session, so this NodeJS App server must validate this JWT. According to this [angular-university.io article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/) section "**Leveraging RS256 Signatures**",

> Instead of installing the public key on the Application server, it's
> much better to have the Authentication server publish the
> JWT-validating public key in a publicly accessible Url.

I found this JWK (not JWT) link https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs from [Google Identity](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) by Erji. Is this the right public key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not exactly an x509 cerificate, but yes that is the JWK is used to validate a given signed JWT.

If we check out the `.well-known` endpoint found in [Googles documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect)

It points us to,

```
jwks_uri    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
```

For the JWKs which contains the currently valid keys for validating a signed JWT. The public key can be built of the information contained in the JWK endpoint

The `n` in is the key itself, the `alg` is the signing algorithm, and the `kid` is the key identifier.

[RFC7517](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517) defines the JWK standard and has full details on the fields